# Built-in function to get the frequency of one word with spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm looking for faster alternatives to NLTK to analyze big corpora and do basic things like calculating frequencies, PoS tagging etc... SpaCy seems great and easy to use in many ways, but I can't find any built-in function to count the frequency of a specific word for example. I've looked at the spaCy documentation, but I can't find a straightforward way to do it. Am I missing something?

What I would like would be the NLTK equivalent of:

```
tokens.count("word") #where tokens is the tokenized text in which the word is to be counted
```

In NLTK, the above code would tell me that in my text, the word "word" appears X number of times.

Note that I've come by the count_by function, but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output maybe ? From what I understood, I may recommend _collections.Counter_ for finding out the frequency of words in a given text.

Comment: I just edited my question to make it clearer, hope this helps. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use spaCy for frequency counts in corpora quite often. This is what I usually do:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

list_of_words = ['run', 'jump', 'catch']

def word_count(string):
    words_counted = 0
    my_string = nlp(string)

    for token in my_string:
        # actual word
        word = token.text
        # lemma
        lemma_word = token.lemma_
        # part of speech
        word_pos = token.pos_
        if lemma_word in list_of_words:
            words_counted += 1
            print(lemma_word)
    return words_counted


sentence = "I ran, jumped, and caught the ball."
words_counted = word_count(sentence)
print(words_counted)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python stdlib includes *collections.Counter* for this kind of purpose. You have not given me an answer if this answer suits your case.

```
from collections import Counter

text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the  ...."

freq = Counter(text.split())
print(freq)

>>> Counter({'the': 6, 'Lorem': 4, 'of': 4, 'Ipsum': 3, 'dummy': 2 ...})

print(freq['Lorem'])

>>> 4
```

#### Alright just to give some time reference, I have used this script,

```
import random, timeit
from collections import Counter

def loadWords():
    with open('corpora.txt', 'w') as corpora:
        randWords = ['foo', 'bar', 'life', 'car', 'wrong',\
                     'right', 'left', 'plain', 'random', 'the']
        for i in range(100000000):
            corpora.write(randWords[random.randint(0, 9)] + " ")

def countWords():
    with open('corpora.txt', 'r') as corpora:
        content = corpora.read()
        myDict = Counter(content.split())
        print("foo: ", myDict['foo'])

print(timeit.timeit(loadWords, number=1))
print(timeit.timeit(countWords, number=1))
```

Results,

```
149.01646934738716
foo: 9998872
18.093295297389773
```

Still I am not sure if this is enough for you.

Comment: About the native "counter" function, I'm afraid that since it relies on the .split function it would not perfectly tokenize the text. This is why I would have rather relied on a function inherent to spaCy, because it could be based on a tokenization made for text mining. I cannot test it right now though, so, maybe it could do the job well after all... Also, I'm afraid that the counter function, which counts every occurrence of every word pre-emptively (if I get it right?) would be really heavy on larger corpora (100M words for example)? Thanks for all the suggestions, it really helps! : )

Comment: It takes around 20 seconds to read 100M words and count them, edited the answer @MitchBuchanon :)

Comment: It's great, and pretty fast indeed, so thanks for that suggestion. The problem remains that the "tokenization" carried out by .split is not as accurate as one which would be carried out by a tokenizer from a text mining lib (ie "word" and "word," are counted as 2 different words, and there are other problems). This is why a solution native to spacy and compatible with its native tokenizer would have been perfect, but as a backup plan this is great, thanks for your time and patience! : )

Comment: You are welcome, you can get around by applying strip to each word if you want to try that out you know. Let's see other answers :)

Comment: @MitchBuchanon you're not limited to splitting the text with `str.split()`, Counter will take any iterable as an argument. If you want to count tokens from a SpaCy doc object, then you can just call `freq = Counter(doc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Updating with this answer as this is the page I found when searching for an answer for this specific problem. I find that this is an easier solution than the ones provided before and that only uses spaCy.

As you mentioned spaCy Doc object has the built in method Doc.count_by. From what I understand of your question it does what you ask for but it is not obvious.

It counts the occurances of an given attribute and returns a dictionary with the attributes hash as key in integer form and the counts.

## Solution

First of all we need to import ORTH from spacy.attr. ORTH is the exact verbatim text of a token. We also need to load the model and provide a text.

```
import spacy
from spacy.attrs import ORTH

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp("apple apple orange banana")
```

Then we create a dictionary of word counts

```
count_dict = doc.count_by(ORTH)
```

You could count by other attributes like LEMMA, just import the attribute you wish to use.

If we look at the dictionary we will se that it contains the hash for the lexeme and the word count.

```
count_dict
```

Results:

```
{8566208034543834098: 2, 2208928596161743350: 1, 2525716904149915114: 1}
```

We can get the text for the word if we look up the hash in the vocab.

```
nlp.vocab.strings[8566208034543834098]
```

Returns

```
'apple'
```

With this we can create a simple function that takes the search word and a count dict created with the Doc.count_by method.

```
def get_word_count(word, count_dict):
    return count_dict[nlp.vocab.strings[word]]
```

If we run the function with our search word 'apple' and the count dict we created earlier

```
get_word_count('apple', count_dict)
```

We get:

```
2
```

https://spacy.io/api/doc#count_by

Comment: This is great, thanks, I'll definitely make sure to check that! : )